# recorrer un diccionario dentro de otro diccionario mediante bucle for

Tags: python, diccionarios

He estado investigando sobre la forma de recorrer un diccionario que contiene otro diccionario como valor mediante un bucle for, pero parece que hasta el momento no he encontrado nada. Por ejemplo este diccionario:

```
t={"a":{"v":4,"w":5},"b":{"y":6,"u":9}}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo recorrer para impimir los values de los diccionarios de adentro?, en este caso 4,5,6 y 9 que es lo que me interesa. Gracias

Comment: `for val in t.values(): for num in val.values(): print(num)`

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```py
t={"a":{"v":4,"w":5},"b":{"y":6,"u":9}}

for llave_primer_diccionario, valor_primer_diccionario in t.items():
    print(f'llave del primer diccionario = {llave_primer_diccionario}')
    for llave_segundo_diccionario, valor_segundo_diccionario in valor_primer_diccionario.items():
        print(f'valor_segundo_diccionario:{llave_segundo_diccionario} y valor_segundo_diccionario {valor_segundo_diccionario}')
```

o si quieres imprimir solo los valores del segundo diccionario

```py
t={"a":{"v":4,"w":5},"b":{"y":6,"u":9}}
for valores_primer_dictionario in t.values():
    for valores_segundo_dictionario in valores_primer_dictionario.values():
        print(valores_segundo_dictionario)
```

En este caso la clave es usar la funcion `values()` esta funcion te retorna los valores de un diccionario.